# LTS 20.04 middle mouse button paste just stopped working yesterday

Tags: gnome, mouse, paste

I use this function all the time and it just stopped working September 3rd. There were some package updates that day, so it had to be one of those because I didn't mess around with any settings that day. In the gnome tweaks the function is enabled and I've tried turning it off and back on. I know there are commands to control these things but I haven't found the right one yet. Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. The middle mouse button just stopped working altogether. Switched the mouse out for another one and things started working as before.

Comment: Funny, same for me! Hardware problem. I thought I fixed it with a reboot yesterday, guess it was intermittent at that point. Now it's a "Windows mouse".

Comment: In my case, I have to press the middle button longer. (OMG, they cannot make a reliable mouse!)